# Detect redirect using SSH tunnel to https?

Tags: linux, ssh, apache-http-server, proxy

I want to redirect my home server via a VPS to the internet, using proxy.

For plain http it does work and it is automatically redirected to https using the certificate of 'my.example.com' installed on the VPS.
The traffic passes through an SSH tunnel to the VPS which serves the content via https as long I have the following connection active:
The local computer has IP 192.168.1.123 and http port 8080.

`ssh -R 81:192.168.1.123:8080 root@myvps`

It uses port 81 on the VPS for proxying port 8080 from my local server.
The VPS automatically redirects all traffic to https port 443.

The section of the ssl.conf on the VPS is this:

```
VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/
    ServerName my.example.com
    LogLevel Debug

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/openims-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/openims.log combined

    SSLCertificateFile      /root/.acme.sh/my.example.com/fullchain.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/.acme.sh/my.example.com/my.example.com.key

      SSLProxyEngine On
      ProxyRequests Off
      ProxyPass / http://localhost:81/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:81/

    #  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    #  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Requests from the VPS port 443 are proxied to localhost:81 (on the VPS) which is proxied to the local server 192.168.1.123:8080.

That works fine.
But when the local server has an https redirect in its httpd.conf for indoor addresses:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond expr "-R '192.168.0.0/16'" [OR]
RewriteCond expr "-R '10.0.0.0/8'" [OR]
RewriteCond expr "-R '127.0.0.0/24'"
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}:8443$1 [R,L]
```

it still redirects to localhost:8443.
In the apache `access_log` of the local server I see that the IP of the request is just this computer from where I surf to https://my.example.com (the VPS). It appears that the local server does not know it is proxied.

How can I add a condition in the Apache configuration that the request comes as a proxy from the VPS ?

Answer (score 0):

I got a 'solution': the HTTP_HOST has port 81 as it is forwarded to port 81 via ssh tunnel from the frontend server (VPS).
Here the section of `httpd.conf` on my local server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !:81$
RewriteCond expr "-R '192.168.0.0/16'" [OR]
RewriteCond expr "-R '10.0.0.0/8'" [OR]
RewriteCond expr "-R '127.0.0.0/24'"
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}:8443$1 [R,
```

which tells that when HTTP_HOST ends with :81 it is from the frontend server so it should not redirect to https and when it is a direct request from the browser it has no :81 at the end so it does redirect.

I first tried with testing on an empty HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR which is the case it is direct on the backend server while when it is a redirect from the frontend server (the VPS) it contains the outdoor IP address of the backend server (my home IP address). So it should only redirect when this is empty.
I added `RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR} ^$` but presumably it always matched. Well a nonempty HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR did match ^$ as if it were empty ?

What am I doing wrong ?